# INPUT DATE VALUE ANGULAR

Tags: html, angular

```js
SERVICE.TS

addP(nome: string, cognome: string, anno_n: string): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post<Partecipanti>(this.partecipantiUrl, {
       nome: nome,
       cognome: cognome,
       anno_n: anno_n 
     }, this.httpOptions).pipe(
       tap((newPartecipante: Partecipanti) => this.log(`partecipante aggiunto w/ id=${newPartecipante.id}`)),
       catchError(this.handleError<Partecipanti>('addP'))
     );
   }
```

```css
COMPONENT.TS

add(nome: string, cognome: string, anno_n: string): void {
      this.PartecipantiService.addP(nome, cognome, anno_n).subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.loadUser();
        })

      }
```

```html
<form class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center float-center" (ngSubmit)="add(nome.value, cognome.value, anno_n.value)" (ngSubmit)="loadUser()" style="justify-content: center;">
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Nome</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" required #nome placeholder="Nome">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Cognome</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" required #cognome placeholder="Cognome">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Data di nascita</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" required #anno_n useValueAsDate placeholder="Data di nascita (GG/MM/AAAA)">
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg">Salva</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

How can I take the date value in my function "add"?
In my function add I have 3 field (name, surname and date), when I call my function add on a button I use (ngSubmit)="add(name.value, surname.value, date...?). What I have to use? Value is for string, I can't find something for Date! This part is on component.html Can you explain me how it works? My input is type="date"

Comment: Please format your question. Read [ask], and [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: user.ts {
name: string,
surname: string,
birth: Date}


service.ts 
add(name: string, surname: string, birth: Date){
code}


user.html
<form (ngSubmit)="add(name.value, surname.value, birth.????)

Comment: I don't know how to take the date value in my function in html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use ngForm. This is the easiest for handling this scenario.

See here the Documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Here is a working example i did: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqgewm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

In Essence you want your HTML look like this:

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="userService.submitForm(form)">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" ngModel required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" id="lastName" ngModel type="text" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" ngModel type="date" required />
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And your Submit function to look like this:

```js
submitForm(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      const user: User = {
        name: form.value['firstName'],
        surname: form.value['lastName'],
        birth: new Date(form.value['dateOfBirth']),
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ty man but it doesn't work!

Comment: What did not work?
I checked the Stackblitz Links and it all seems to work.
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqgewm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html)


I would need more Details on what specifically you expect and what did not work.

Comment: My console don't show the date, because I have a problem in the module